# WakefulReceiver fires on all versions but 4.0.3

Tags: android, push-notification, android-manifest, google-cloud-messaging

I've got a WakefulReceiver and an IntentService set up for push notifications, just the way they are shown in the GCM tutorial.
I've gotten the notifications without issue in most devices version on Android versions 4.1.x and up (.2, .3, .4) no problem.

However on version 4.0.3 my wakeful receiver is not even firing. I've gone over the permissions since that's what I've seen on the net, but I've thrice checked the permissions and they seem to be fine.

Is there a known issue with 4.0.3 or some other lead?

Here's my Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.companyname.mobile.appname"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="0.2" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.companyname.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.companyname.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/myLauncherIcon"
    android:label="@string/launcher_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:logo="@drawable/myLogo"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appname.activity.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appname.activity.HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.companyname.appname.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.companyname.appname" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.companyname.appname.GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```